# Percorrer e contar registros de um JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Eu tenho um código Python que eu consigo exibir na tela todos os registros de JSON, só que eu preciso trazer apenas o campo `'Nome'` e o `count` de cada um.

Primeiro que ele traz com `[]` (formato lista) e eu preciso da informação limpa, mas não sei como conseguir isso.

Ex.:

```
    {  
   'contract_id':300166,
   'plan_id':15,
   'total_value':39.9,
   'installment_value':0.0,
   'agent_code':'nenhum',
   'customer_name':'Rafael Moura dos Santos',
   'customer_cpf':'54745361602',
   'status':'cancelado',
   'payment_link':None,
   'installments':12,
   'payment_method':None,
   'validity_start_date':'2017-11-07 00:00:00',
   'validity_end_date':'2018-11-07 00:00:00',
   'addresses':[  
      {  
         'street':'rua da ovelha',
         'number':'999',
         'additional_details':'bloco do completo',
         'zipcode':'07121010',
         'district':'water',
         'city':'agua',
         'state':'SP',
         'country':'BR'
      }
   ],
   'phones':[  
      {  
         'category':'mobile',
         'extension':'',
         'number':'5511981013752'
      }
   ],
   'customer':{  
      'name':'Rafael Moura dos Santos',
      'cpf':'54745361602',
      'birth':'1988-06-28',
      'gender':'',
      'marital_status':''
   },
   'links':[  

   ],
   'policies':[  
      {  
         'policy_id':210,
         'policy_number':'PA-000090',
         'certificate_link':'',
         'value':39.9,
         'status':'ativo',
         'product_id':1,
         'metadata':{  

         },
         'covered_goods':[  
            {  
               'Nome':'Rex',
               'Cão ou gato':'Cão',
               'Cor do pelo':'Marrom',
               'Data de nascimento':'29/03/2010',
               'Tamanho':'M',
               'Macho ou Fêmea':'Macho',
               'Raça':'Arc',
               'Doença ou lesão preexistente':'Não',
               'Descreva preexistência':'',
               'Vacinação em dia':'Sim'
            },
            {  
               'Nome':'Rex',
               'Cão ou gato':'Cão',
               'Cor do pelo':'Marrom',
               'Data de nascimento':'29/03/2010',
               'Tamanho':'M',
               'Macho ou Fêmea':'Macho',
               'Raça':'Arc',
               'Doença ou lesão preexistente':'Não',
               'Descreva preexistência':'',
               'Vacinação em dia':'Sim'
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Código:

```
import json
import requests
import csv
import collections

url = 
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 

} 

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 

res = json.loads(response.text)

output = []

for c in res['response']:
     goods = []
     if len(c['policies']) > 0:
         goods = [good["Nome"] for good in c['policies'] [0]['covered_goods']]

     output.append(goods)


d = {x:goods.count(x) for x in goods}
print(d)


print(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua iteração não está adequada para sua saída. Quando você conta o `output` para colocar em `d`, só vai ter o resultado do último contrato iterado. Então vamos fazer umas modificações:

```
output = []

for c in res['response']: # trocar c por contract pra ficar mais fácil de entender
     goods = [] # remover essa variável que não será mais necessária
     if len(c['policies']) > 0:
         goods = [good["Nome"] for good in c['policies'] [0]['covered_goods']]   
     output.append(goods) # alocar a linha de cima direto em output

d = {x:output.count(x) for x in output}
```

Aqui está o código com as correções. Ele percorre todos as fichas presentes em todos os contratos e aloca o nome em `output`:

```
output = []

for contract in res['response']: # tomei a liberdade de mudar o nome da variável
 if len(contract['policies']) > 0:
     for policy in contract['policies']: # tem que iterar aqui também!
         for profile in policy['covered_goods']:
             if 'Nome' in profile.keys():
                 output.append(profile['Nome'])

d = {x:output.count(x) for x in output}
```

No finalzinho, onde você coloca `print(d)`, coloque:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)
```

O seu retorno será limpo, sem nenhum componente a mais além do dado:

> Rex 2

Nesse código, `k` é o valor da chave do dicionário, que na verdade é o campo `Nome` do seu arquivo, e `v` é o valor do dicionário, que na verdade é o `count` que você fez. É possível também você exibir algo mais elaborado como:

> Rex: 2

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,': ',v, sep='')
```

Tem também como guardar isso em uma string nesse formato:

```
string = [k+': '+str(v)+'\n' for k,v in d.items()]
string = ''.join(string)        
print(string)
```

Comment: Oii... obrigado por responder, eu tentei mas ele pega o valor do ultimo item, no caso foi um cão com nome 'cão', tipo, ele ignora os outros...

Comment: Já sei o que acontece. Vou te ajudar.

Comment: Fiz as modificações com base no que você disse. Se tiver mais alguma coisa, sugiro até mudar a pergunta para caso alguma outra pessoa tente ajudar.

Comment: Oi, deu erro: TypeError: string indices must be integers.. já pesquisei mas não consegui arrumar...

Comment: Eu tinha removido o índice da variável `res['response']` para simular aqui no meu computador. Devolvi ele pro código e você pode tentar de novo. Daqui pra frente eu não consigo te ajudar com a informação que você me passou. Por quê? Porque eu precisaria saber como é a estrutura da sua varável `res`. A parte que você mandou é relativa apenas à estrutura de um contrato.

Comment: Uma coisa que me chamou a atenção é o fato de você colocar `c['policies'][0]`. Só posso ter uma policy em cada contrato? Se puder ter mais, tem que iterar ali também.

Comment: Meu Deusss, funcionou.... acho q entendi as suas pontuações, vou estudar todas elas! Gratidão!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou! Te contar que foi a primeira vez que coloquei a mão num JSON! Ah, e não esquece de marcar a resposta como escolhida! ;)

Comment: Como eu faço isso ? Hahahaha

Comment: Do lado das respostas dadas, perto de onde tem uma seta pra cima e outra pra baixo, existe um V na cor cinza. Quando você marca ele, fica verde. [Aqui mostra como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg) e [aqui explica o porquê de fazer isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).